# Copying files from one existing app service to another existing app service slot on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azureportal, azure-deployment

I've created App Service with two slots, Production and Staging. Deployment was made on Production slot. Now I need to copy all files from production slot to staging.  Is there way to do it in scope of arm template when deploying? If not, how to do it easily as separated action ?

Comment: Sounds like this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/how-to-copy-complete-site-from-production-slot-to-staging-slot-in-azure-paas Short answer: deploy to the staging slot then swap

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , deployment was made by arm templates, and it set up whole sitecore environment, databases and solr as well. All I need is to copy files from one app service slot to another, without running azure arm template deployment again.

We are trying to write one arm template that will setup whole sitecore environment on  both slots (prod, staging) which will use the same db's and solr env

Comment: Can't you parameterise the slot in your arm template? Then you run the same tempate twice. Failing that, here's a guide on using powershell to peform slot actions. Whatever script is deploying your arm template can call this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#automate-with-powershell